# add dynamic html table between two rows of jquery datatable using slideToggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

```
 - Here Sample code for table creation in JQuery.
`
var oTable = $('#tblData').dataTable( {
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "sScrollY": 125,
                    "aaData": [],
                    "aaSorting": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
                    "asStripeClasses": [ 'strip1', 'strip1'],
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "sTitle": "", "sClass": "text-left" },
]
                } ); 
`
```

- after response here my JS for add data.

`function result(response)
{
    var TempData = '<div id="DB_Data"> <table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td>Data</td><td>1stColomn</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table></div>'; //here for sample two rows with two colomns

        var temp = "$('#DB_Data').slideToggle();"; // for call table 
        var ColButton = '<img class="" onClick="'+temp+'" src="../right.png"  width="20px" />';
    // for button creation
    var arr =[];
    $(response.Data).each(function(index, element) {

             var t = ["",this.Date,this,time.....];

            arr.push(t); 
        });

    var oTable = $('#tblData').dataTable();
        oTable.fnClearTable();
        $('#tblData').dataTable().fnAddData(arr);
}`

    - here how to create/show table of DB_Data when click on 1st column of toggle button.
    - save my days.what is wrong in my above code
    - image is :
        ![enter image description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpWHN.jpg
```

Comment: Save My Days Please...

Comment: I don't mind helping but I need some info. What is the desired result of your code.  Are you just trying to create html tables on a button click using jquery?

Comment: in html page - id=tblData table created.when i call server i got this table related row data like Date and nd time and name(16-11-2014,05:30,KKS....).

Comment: and i given  button toggle for when i click particuler row button clicking will showing under that row another dynamic table.

Comment: you mean something like this : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml

idea is add tr and td then table under needed row that you want to expand

Comment: may you add your html code? or use http://jsfiddle.net/ so I can try fix your code, save our minutes to save your days.

Comment: Please once look in http://jsfiddle.net/rajinikanth06/9z2mh826/

Comment: You code is not commented very well so it is a little hard to follow. Do you ever add any data to the arr array variable in your code using the push() method?  As it stands right now it looks like that array is not being used?

Comment: If you can make your fiddle produce some sample output so we can help fix your problem it would go a long way.